# Grouping data by time intervals in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
0      930  260.915508 2020-07-06 15:35:00
1      950  246.900944 2020-07-06 15:35:00
2      930  258.750335 2020-07-06 15:40:00
3      950  254.532348 2020-07-06 16:40:00
4      970  216.844755 2020-07-06 16:40:00
```

And i have a starting date: `2020-07-06 12:00`. I need to group my Pandas Dataframe in time intervals of four hours starting from the starting date, so: `2020-07-06 12:00` > `2020-07-06 16:00` > `2020-07-06 20:00` and so on.

So the expected output of my dataframe, becomes this:

```
0      930  260.915508 2020-07-06 16:00:00
1      950  246.900944 2020-07-06 16:00:00
2      930  258.750335 2020-07-06 16:00:00
3      950  254.532348 2020-07-06 20:00:00
4      970  216.844755 2020-07-06 20:00:00
```

Explanation: if a row in the dataframe has `datetime` `15:35`, the new time needs to be `16:00`. If the time is `16:01`, the new time will become `20:00`.

I don't know if this is doable at all with Pandas only, i'm afraid i need to use more code to do that, but i first wanted to see if anyone here was able to do that with only Pandas. Any kind of advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.ceil`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html) by `4H` interval:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.ceil('4H')
print (df)
   col1        col2                date
0   930  260.915508 2020-07-06 16:00:00
1   950  246.900944 2020-07-06 16:00:00
2   930  258.750335 2020-07-06 16:00:00
3   950  254.532348 2020-07-06 20:00:00
4   970  216.844755 2020-07-06 20:00:00
```

EDIT: For add hours by first datetime is possible extract hours with modulo by `4` and add timedelta, if first datetime is `2020-07-06 12:00` because `12 % 4 = 0` is added `0 hours`, if first datetime is `2020-07-06 13:00` because `12 % 4 = 1` is added `1 hour`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

first = pd.Timedelta(df['date'].iat[0].hour % 4, unit='h')
print (first)

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.ceil('4H') + first
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! But is there any way to specify from which date it needs to start counting the 4h intervals? For example, if i set the time to 13:00, the intervals will be 17:00 > 21:00 and so on

Comment: @San9096 - Added solution for this.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you a lot! I came up with another solution but this is a lot more efficient and simpler

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dt.ceil`:

```
df['time_col'] = df['time_col'].dt.ceil('4H')
```

Output:

```
0  0  930  260.915508 2020-07-06 16:00:00
1  1  950  246.900944 2020-07-06 16:00:00
2  2  930  258.750335 2020-07-06 16:00:00
3  3  950  254.532348 2020-07-06 20:00:00
4  4  970  216.844755 2020-07-06 20:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Do you know if there is a way to set the starting time from which it needs to count the four hours intervals? For example, if i set 13:00 it will be 13:00 > 17:00 > 21:00, if i set 11:00 it will be 15:00 > 19:00 > 23:00